# Android hardware acceleration webview crash

Tags: android

Through the android market, for my app users are reporting a significant number of UnsupportedOperation Exceptions. The stack trace points to a drawPicture() call made from inside webview codes. I am indeed using webviews in my app.

I know that drawPicture() is not supported when HWA is turned on, but in this case the call is coming from inside a webview. Are there special steps I need to take to ensure the webview will not use this method?

Unfortunately I have not been able to reproduce the issue, but it is definitely being seen by users.

The stack trace:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at android.view.GLES20Canvas.drawPicture(GLES20Canvas.java:753)
at android.webkit.WebView.drawCoreAndCursorRing(WebView.java:4128)
at android.webkit.WebView.drawContent(WebView.java:3797)
at android.webkit.WebView.onDraw(WebView.java:3862)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:9286)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:8749)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2554)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2189)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:8747)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2554)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2189)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:9289)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:8749)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2554)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2189)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:8747)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2554)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2189)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:8747)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2554)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2189)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:9289)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:419)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1923)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:8749)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2554)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2189)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:8747)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2554)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2189)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:9289)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:8749)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2554)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2189)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:8747)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2554)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2189)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:8747)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2554)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2189)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:9289)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:419)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1923)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:8749)
at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:609)
at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1600)
at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1416)
at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:2046)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: This is an interesting bug. When WebView draws on a hardware accelerated canvas, it does not use drawPicture(), but a completely different code path. If you can come up with a repro case, please send it to me and I'll forward it to the WebView team.

Comment: Not sure why this had been downvoted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using restorePicture? ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#restorePicture(android.os.Bundle, java.io.File) )

That method is not supported with hardware acceleration (and the method is deprecated, so you should be getting off of it anyway). As a workaround you can set the webview to be a software layer until you load some other content.

Comment: I was using restorePicture(), so maybe that is the root cause. That code path is not being executed for me, but perhaps it does get executed for some corner cases (e.g. low memory on device). I'll continue testing and see if removing restorePicture() helps.